# CakePHP custom functions used in controllers and models

Tags: function, cakephp, redirect, controller

I'm a function, CakePHP and OOPHP noob so please be patient with me ;)

I have a 301 redirect script I use in the view function of the controllers to compare the slug in the url to the slug in the db and if they don't match 301 redirect to the url with the right slug

I'm trying to turn it into custom functions but I haven't had much success...

This is the code:

```
$pieces = explode('__', $this->params['pass'][0]);

    if (!isset($pieces[2])) {
        if ($pieces[1] != $this->Smartphone->field('slug')) {
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->Smartphone->field('id').'__'.$this->Smartphone->field('slug')));
        }
    }
```

My guess is a function would look something like:

```
public function 301redirect($model) {
    $pieces = explode('__', $this->params['pass'][0]);

if (!isset($pieces[2])) {
    if ($pieces[1] != $this->Smartphone->field('slug')) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->$model->field('id').'__'.$this->$model->field('slug')));
    }
}
```

}

Can you guys tell me what I should put where to get this function to work?

Thnx!

Comment: You need to put 4 spaces (or a tab) before each line of code for SO to format it as code. Also, check the preview of your question/answer before you submit it. Lastly, it's common programming etiquette (and best practice) to format your code in a sane and consistent manner. Don't just insert spaces/tabs randomly. Indentation should reflect the structure of your code and enhance readability.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a custom Component ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component )

Components allow you to package features together and share them between Controllers.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I'm getting closer. I can now get a simple function working but I'm stuck because lines like $this->params['pass'][0] and $this->$model->field('slug') don't seem to work inside a component.

Comment: You can pass them into your Component method as parameters: $this->Component->method($this->params, $this->$model->field('slug'))

(makes it easier to unit test too!)